# SQL Query - error #1064 'having count(*) > 1 LIMIT 0, 30'

Tags: sql, phpmyadmin

This is the query I'm trying create using SQL on phpMyAdmin:

```
SELECT DISTINCT Client_Order.orderID, Client.Title, Client.First_Name, Set_Product.setName, Client_Order.orderDATE, count( * )
FROM Client_Order
INNER JOIN Set_Product ON Set_Product.setID = Set_Product.setID
INNER JOIN Client ON Client.clientID = Client.clientID
GROUP BY Client_Order.orderID
ORDER BY Client.First_Name ASC
having count(*) > 1
```

But I'm getting an error saying:

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'having count(*) > 1 LIMIT 0, 30' at line 7
```

How can i display my query because without the count I am just getting multiple duplicates.

Comment: What does LIMIT 0, 30 mean and why is it in the error message but not in your code?

Comment: The `HAVING` clause should come right after `GROUP BY`, before `ORDER BY`.

Comment: LIMIT in mySQL seems to be roughly equivalent to TOP in T-SQL.

Comment: Thank you Micheal Berkowski

Comment: Put `HAVING` before `ORDER BY ` clause

Comment: @RossPresser -- I know that -- my point is that it is not the code that is giving the error message -- he should post the code that is giving the error message -- that would make it easier to solve the problem.